# Call a function inside another function and then stop it javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I have a file input on whose change two functions, `f()` and `colorit()`, are called. I want to stop function `colorit()` if a specified condition is not met in `f()`. However as soon as the file is selected both functions fire up.

```
<body>
    <div class="dClass">
        <input type="file" class="iClass" />
    </div>

    <script> 
        function f(){
            if () { 
                // if image selected does not meet requirements
                // how to stop colorit(); function here ??
                return false;
            }
            else {
               alert("done");
            }
        }

        $('.iClass').change(function() { 
           f(); // calling function f
        });

        $(function() {
           $('.dClass').colorit();
           //note: colorit() function also comes to action as soon as a file is selected through .iClass
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Color it is a function to change the div's background, and what I want is if the image does not meets the conditions don't implement as background

Comment: ...and your colorit function runs `onload`...is it a loop or something? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

Remove -

```
$(function() {
   $('.dClass').colorit();
}
```

If you only want `colorit()` to work if `f()` succeeds.

Define `f()` like -

```
function f(obj){
    if () { // if image selected does not meet requirements
       // how to stop colorit(); function here ??
       return false;
    }
    else {
       obj.colorit();
       alert("done");
    }
}
```

So that you can initiate `colorit` with the object if sicceeds.

And call `f()` like -

```
$('.iClass').change(function() { 
   f($('.dClass')); // calling function f
});
```

Another way would be -

```
function f(obj){
    if () { // if image selected does not meet requirements
       // how to stop colorit(); function here ??
       return false;
    }
    else {
       obj.data('fdone', 1);
       alert("done");
    }
}
```

And

```
$('.iClass').change(function() { 
   f($('.dClass')); // calling function f
   if($(this).data('fdone') == 1) {
      $('.dClass').colorit();
   }
});
```

And -

```
<input type="file" class="iClass" data-fdone='0' />
```

Comment: Yeah seems worthy shud give it a try

Comment: are you getting the alert?

Comment: Colorit() is a gigantic function coming from a jquery plugin, does that effects on its functionality ??

Answer (score 0):

You can force stop a function execution by using this in it, not recomanded , but this is a way

```
throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');
```

Comment: What's this throw new ??

Comment: The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.

Comment: can u make us a JsFiddle?

Comment: first fiddle, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/devaaroon11/q4pL1gn6/4/) .in this one wheather the condition of f() is met or not colorit() cahnges the background image. second fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/devaaroon11/kfr15Lwe/4/) . in this one f() verifies the if condition but color it does not works.

Comment: in the jsFiddle u use jquery but no library was selected, does it work or you just pasted there the code again? and got a question, colorit() is a plugin? or something u made? what are your intentions? to upload an image and then set it as background if it passes some conditions?